# Error on dynamic array creation on c++

Tags: c++

I have a question for my homework. I have written a Student class and its constructor just holds id and name of a single student. Here is the constructor and get method: (I will not put the other part because irrelevant)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleStudent.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(const int sid , const string sname ) {
    studentId = sid;
    studentName = sname;
}
string Student::getStudentName() {
    return studentName; 
} 

void Student::operator=(const Student &right) {
    if (&right != this) {
        if (studentId != right.studentId) {
            studentId = right.studentId;
        }
        if (studentName != right.studentName) {
            studentName = right.studentName;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, studentId and studentName is declared in the header at the private part as int and string, respectively.

Here is the test part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SimpleSRS.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Student* x = new Student[1];
    Student* s1 = new Student(1,"er");
    x[0] = *s1;    
    cout << x[0].getStudentName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

I cannot figure out the problem. Thank you

Edit: Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef __SIMPLE_STUDENT_H
#define __SIMPLE_STUDENT_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = 0);
    Student();
    ~Student();
    Student(const Student &studentToCopy);
    void operator=(const Student &right);
    int getStudentId();
    string getStudentName();
private:
    int studentId;
    string studentName;
};
#endif
```

Comment: This really needs a [mcve]

Comment: @FredLarson It has to [otherwise it doesnt compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005d579e7236e4d0). That being said yes MVCE.

Comment: @Borgleader: Oh yes, you're right. I was thinking there was a compile error, but on closer inspection the error shown is a runtime error.

Comment: I think you should post your header file too, since in main you're including a different header than in the `simplestudent.cpp` file.

Comment: @Eray Erturk I cannot reproduce the error using the presented code if to add the default constructor.

Comment: @n.m. in addition to those, there exists a getId method, empty destructer and empty copy constructor. Also, I will edit the assignment operator above.

Comment: My strong suspicion is that the default constructor does something like this: `Foo() : i(0), s(nullptr) {}` which causes [a logic_error in `std::string`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69e2975094f5d05d). The fix is to remove `s(nullptr)`. (Called it: `const string sname = 0`)

Comment: @Eray Erturk So if you defined the copy assignment operator explicitly then it seems the error is in its implementation.

Comment: The right way to solve the problem is using a debugger. Trace the program step by stepv observe how variable come ro be, change values, and cease to exist; note at which point the exception is thrown; look at current values of the variables; figure out what went wrong. If still unable to, post your findings together with a way to reproduce them (this means a [mcve]).

Comment: general advice, run under a debugger. You will immedatley see what line is failing. Second - google for the error message, you will get instant hits (I just did) telling you the exact cause

Comment: OK `const string sname = 0` what do you expect to accomplish with this?

Comment: and for the first time today. Use std::vector rather than arrays. Life always goes better with std::vector

Comment: @n.m. curious about which constructor will get called for `Student()` since both constructors match (one with defaults, one with no args)

Comment: I have used debugger on visual studio, and it says that the problem is with this line:  Student* s1 = new Student(1,"er");

Comment: @pm100 [it should be ambiguous](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05b950810ec9719f)

Comment: This is the exception :::Unhandled exception at 0x0095D6F0 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Comment: It looks like your compiler has a bug. It allows you to define both `Student::Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = 0)` and `Student::Student()` and then call the default constructor. This is not legal in C++.

Answer (score 2):

you are failing because you are passing null to the constructor of std::string. THis is not allowed. You do it here

```
  Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = 0);
```

Its also not clear why you have 2 constructors

```
 Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = 0);
    Student();
```

These are basically identical.

I would simply remove the first one. Now studentName will get default constructed (empty)

Comment: I cannot delete the first one because I am not allowed to delete it by the instructor, also I changed  "sname = 0" to "sname = "" " but nothing changed again.

Comment: @ErayErturk if your instructor gave you this `Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = 0);` then your instructor is either incompetent or sadistic. Sorry to inform you.

Comment: @n.m. actually it was my mistake, I miswrote it, sorry for that, he gave us that :: Student(const int sid = 0, const string sname = "");

Comment: @ErayErturk that's a different matter! This one `Student();` is still an error.